# Displaying mysql data with headings and subheadings taking dynamically from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database

```
id      area_name       area_district   area_shire
1       Harborne        Birmingham      West Midlands
2       Edgbaston       Birmingham      West Midlands
3       Halesowen       Dudley          West Midlands
4       Rugby                           Warwickshire   
5       Nuneaton                        Warwickshire
```

How do i get this to display,

```
West Midlands (main heading)

Birmingham (sub heading)

    Harborne 
    Edgbaston

Dudley (sub heading)

Halesowen

Warwickshire (main heading)

Rugby 
Nuneaton
```

Is there a single while loop that can achieve this?

**EDIT:** Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Areas_Covered ORDER BY ID"); //fetch the results

// convert results into an array
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):
    $area_name = $rows ['area_name'];
    $area_district = $rows ['area_district'];
    $area_name_url = str_replace(' ', '_', $area_name);
    echo "<a href=\"Driveway_Cleaning_$area_name_url.php\">$area_name</a><br>";
endwhile;
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Comment: @Jason please don't link to that resource, its dangerously bad. http://w3fools.com

Comment: @Dagon Thanks for the details, didn't realize the issues surrounding the site.

Comment: @SeanBright                                                          $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Areas_Covered ORDER BY ID");

//fetch the results / convert results into an array
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

$area_name = $rows ['area_name'];
$area_district = $rows ['area_district'];  
$area_name_url = str_replace(' ', '_', $area_name);

echo "<a href=\"Driveway_Cleaning_$area_name_url.php\">$area_name</a><br>";
endwhile;

Comment: +1 for updating your question and showing us what you have tried.

Comment: @Jason: Definitely don't link to w3schools, there are some pretty bad SQL injection examples here for example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you may want to 'normalise' your data first but thats another question.

I would iterate the rows and check for changes. I would do something like:

```
$area_shire = '';
$area_district = '';
$area_name = '';

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

    if($rows['area_shire'] != $area_shire) {

        echo '<h1>'.$rows['area_shire'].'</h1>';
        $area_shire = $rows['area_shire'];
    }

    /* do the same for district using h2 and name using h3 */

endwhile;
```

Comment: When you say do the same for district and for name, do you mean in the same while loop?

Comment: @user1880357 yes exactly where the comment is. Then after that, still in the loop,add any content specific to that record.

Comment: Many thanks that worked a treat. What i am actually trying to do is echo a list of urls. I have added                      $area_shire_url = str_replace(' ', '_', $area_shire);
$area_district_url = str_replace(' ', '_', $area_district);
$area_name_url = str_replace(' ', '_', $area_name);
                                                                              I have changed the three echos to echo '<a href=\"Tree_Surgery_'.$area_shire_url.'.php\">h2>'.$rows['area_shire'].'<br></h2>';                                              area_shire = $rows['area_shire'];}    etc etc

Comment: The result is the area_names_url is using the previous variable, and the other two are showing no variable in the url. Do you know how i can solve this?